# How do I use a variable for an options (DropDown) parameter?

Tags: build, azure-devops

I have an Azure-DevOps build with a task that uses an options (DropDown) parameter.  I would like to dynamically set the parameter using a variable such as $(DatabaseEnvironment).  How can I use this variable when the UI does not allow text to be entered?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the field editable. Add this to your definition for the field:

```
"properties": {
                "EditableOptions": "True"
            }
```